# Bind event to jQuery.post and callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am using jQuery.post a lot in my project and every time the browser sends a post request, I want to show a preloader while the request is in process and then stop the preloader when i get the reply form the server:

```
var params = {'action':'get_customer_info', 'customerID':4};

preloader.start();
$.post('ajax/url', params, function(response){
    preloader.stop();

    responseHandler(response);
});
```

Instead of adding the preloader.start() and preloader.stop() lines every time I call jQuery's post, I'd like to bind/trigger events on before the jQuery.post as well on the success/fail handlers.

I know how to bind and trigger events in general, but I'm not sure how I would do this with the $.post and handlers.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up the global ajax events, that way the preloader shows on every ajax request

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
    preloader.start();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    preloader.stop();
});
```

Or you could create your own `post` function

```
function post(url, params) {
    preloader.start();
    return $.post('ajax/url', params, function(response){
        preloader.stop();
    });
}
```

To be used like

```
post('ajax/url', params).done(function(response) {
    responseHandler(response);
});
```